# Asus ROG Crosshair VIII Hero does not detect m.2 - how to debug

Tags: ssd, bios, m.2

I am a bit lost here: I'm building a new PC from scratch, using a Asus ROG Crosshair VIII Hero with an m.2 SSD "Corsair Force Series MP600" (NVMe PCIe Gen4 x4 M.2 SSD).

The SSD is plugged into M2_1 and fits fine.

However, the BIOS won't detect it and does not show it under devices. There's nothing suitable I could find on the internet on this matter - except for some references to nonexist BIOS settings.

Is there anyone who's had the same issues or could help me find a way how to debug this?

Thanks a lot, 
Matthias

Comment: Update the [BIOS](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-Crosshair-VIII-Hero/HelpDesk_BIOS/) and check again.

Comment: not working unfortunately - it won't detect any USB drives and "update via internet" claims that there is no network connection (which is not correct)

Comment: I have an M.2 NvME that doesn't get listed in the sata devices (ASUS TUF Mk2), but that's because the m.2 slots are running in PCI mode (set in BIOS). If I run it in sata mode, it takes the place of whatever is connected to sata0/1 (which I don't want as all my sata slots are full). I wonder if it shows up in the boot menu anyway?

Comment: There's a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1349499/motherboard-uefi-doesnt-detect-m-2-ssd-drive?rq=1) (although different motherboard) that might have some suggestions that could still be valid for your MoBo